# iOS: possible to superimpose barbuttonitem on other barbuttonitem and swap them

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem

I have a screen that displays some info in a textview and I would like the user to be able to edit it.

Right now, I have an edit button on the right side of the navigation bar that I create in code as follows:

```
 UIBarButtonItem *editButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(gotoEdit)];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = editButton;
```

For editing, I could launch a new view controller but it would be cleaner, I think, to just use the textview.editable property to make the text view editable.

However, I would then need to change the title and function of the uibarbuttonitem from edit to save.

You apparently cannot change the title of a system edit button and I'd just as soon not create a custom bar button item although this may ultimately prove necessary.

It is possible to hide bar button items by making their color clear and disabling interaction.  Therefore, I had the idea of putting two in the same place and hiding and showing them accordingly.

Hence my question.  Is it possible to put two in the same place?

Thanks for any ideas on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using storyboards...you can drag and drop a `UIButton` to the `rightBarButtonItem`. Make this button a property and set the initial title to "Edit".

In the Action:

```
- (IBAction) editButton (id){
    if(!isEditing){
         // Prep for editing
         [self.editButton setTitle:"Save" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         isEditing = true;
    }else{
         // Prep for save
         [self.editButton setTitle:"Edit" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
         isEditing = false;
    }
}
```